# Local maximum and local minimum

Tags: calculus

What is the basic differences of critical ponts, stationary point,saddle point,turning point,point of inflexion

Comment: Is this a homework problem?

Comment: @user702641: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point

Answer (score 2):

[**Critical point :**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics))

**In the case of functions of a real variable,** a critical point is a point in the domain of the function where the function is either not differentiable or the derivative is equal to zero.

**When dealing with complex variables,** a critical point is, similarly, a point in the function's domain where it is either not holomorphic or the derivative is equal to zero.

**For a function of several real variables,** a critical point is a value in its domain where the gradient is undefined or is equal to zero.

[**Stationary point :**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point)

**In calculus,** a stationary point of a differentiable function of one variable is a point on the graph of the function where the function's derivative is zero.

**For a differentiable function of several real variables,** a stationary point is a point on the surface of the graph where all its partial derivatives are zero (equivalently, the gradient is zero).

[**Saddle point :**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point)

In mathematics, a saddle point or minimax point is a point on the surface of the graph of a function where the slopes (derivatives) in orthogonal directions are all zero (a **critical point**), but which is not a local extremum of the function.

[**Turning point :**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point)

A turning point is a point at which the derivative changes sign.

[**Point of inflexion :**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point)

In differential calculus, an inflection point, point of inflection, flex, or inflection (British English: inflexion) is a point on a continuous plane curve at which the curve changes from being concave (concave downward) to convex (concave upward), or vice versa.

**Notes:**

- All stationary points are critical points but not all critical points are stationary points.
- For a differentiable function, critical point is the same as stationary point.
- If the function is differentiable, then a turning point is a stationary point; however not all stationary points are turning points.
- If the function is twice differentiable, the stationary points that are not turning points are horizontal inflection points.
- For a second-order linear autonomous system, a critical point is a saddle point if the characteristic equation has one positive and one negative real eigenvalue.
- A function can have critical points that are not turning points. For example, $~0~$ is a critical point of the function $~f(x)=x^3~$ but not a turning point of the function.
- An inflection point does not have to be a stationary point, but if it is, then it would also be a saddle point.